# SonataAdmin Bundle is already extended by two bundles

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm having a problem with Sonata admin Bundle , i have already exteneded sonata admin bundle in one of my bundles , now i want to do the same in an another bundle so that the admin manage the entities from both bundles , but i keep getting this error : Sonata admin bundle is directly extended by two bundles ..  Any ideas ?

Comment: To add admins, you shouls not extend a bundle. Extending a bundle means you want to override something

Comment: .. That's clear now thank's a lot Wouter